# What does というのは mean right after a name?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 芳山（yoshiyama:one of the characters)くんというのは、やさしくてかわいいけど、少し[母性愛]{ぼせいあい}[過多]{かた}なんじゃないか？

What does *toiunoha* mean in this context? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

This would simply mean "Yoshiyama-kun is..." but it is used to emphasize this person/compare, maybe in relation to previous sentence it would make sense. It is written like "This man, Yoshiyama, is...".

Comment: What about the "なんじゃないか" ?